# Oscillatory integral estimates imply sublevel set estimates

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

I am looking for a particular source for the following type of theorem:

If
$$\Bigg{|}\int_{\mathbb{R^d}} e^{i\lambda \phi(x)} \psi(x) dx\Bigg{|} = O(\lambda^{-p}),$$
then, letting $E_\varepsilon = \{ x: |\phi(x)|<\varepsilon\},$
$$\Bigg{|}\int_{\mathbb{R^d}} \chi_{E_\varepsilon} \psi(x) dx\Bigg{|} = O(\varepsilon^p).$$

I think I saw this in some of Tao's notes as a *named* theorem (modulo any details I left out about $\phi, \psi,$ etc.). I searched through all of his relevant course notes recently, but couldn't find what I remembered. Dozens of papers reprove this result in one way or another, but I'm looking particularly for a source where they provide this as a named theorem.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that you are remembering this result being a corollary of another named result, like van der Corput's lemma?

Comment: I guess it's possible, but it definitely wasn't van der Corput's lemma. The standard technique to prove this implication is to smoothen out the characteristic function, then take a Fourier transform, and this is unrelated to van der Corput. I'm sure I saw the name in some notes...

Comment: this theorem confuses me: stationary phase arguments would tell me that what matters are regions where $\nabla\phi\approx 0$, not regions where $|\phi|\approx 0$.

Comment: Math is confusing sometimes. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_lemma_(harmonic_analysis)

Comment: (Also, I didn't write the standard hypotheses on $\phi, \psi$, etc., as I was hoping an expert would reply.)